# location.hash returns previous position

Tags: jquery, window.location, hashchange

I have a panel with Id="*panelbar*" , and when I click on it, I have a function

```
$('#panelbar').bind('click', func1);
```

in func1(): I have this Code:

```
location.hash;
```

but , the code returns the **previous hash**, not **new one**. how can I get the new hash in each click?

Comment: `location.hash` always returns the current hash (the one you see in the address bar), what do you mean it returns the previous one?

Comment: If location.hash return the previous hash its because you did not change it in the propper way. Can you write how are you changing the hash ?

Comment: If you're binding the event listener to a anchor, it will take the the hash before it changes. If you want to get the hash from the anchor, you should get it by calling this ``$(this).attr('href')`` inside your function ``func1``